# Recommended ODBC-JDBC bridge driver for Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

Sun's JDBC-ODBC bridge driver was meant as a short term solution when JDBC drivers weren't widely available, not recommended for production, etc etc.  Yet due to a conjunction of many stupid decisions made on the part of many others, we're forced to use this to connect to Oracle rather than JDBC.

Are there *any* ODBC-JDBC bridge drivers out there, better than Sun's implementation...*which are also free?*

Comment: Honestly: try to get rid of whoever made the decision to use ODBC and switch to JDBC thin driver. Using the ODBC driver against Oracle from within a Java application is plain stupid (no offense against you!)

Comment: Yep, but such stupidity is forced upon us.. supposedly it's due to limitations of the system which 'owns' the Oracle db. Some proprietary something being done in a junky custom odbc driver, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options:

[Easysoft JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html)

[Openlinksw Single-Tier JDBC to ODBC Bridge](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/)

Comment: Please note that we offer a similar solution: https://www.progress.com/jdbc/sequelink

Answer (score 1):

Other options ( in second answer due to strange security check in stackoverflow, possibly they do not want new users)

[Openlinksw Multi-Tier JDBC to ODBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-mt/)

[Simba SDK allows to build custom jdbc or odbc drivers and bridges](http://www.simba.com)